# Running hundreds of http request per minutes in java

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I'm developing an application in J2SE, which would regularly visit a high number of websites.
High means several hundred, and regularly means per minutes - so, there would be about 500 http requests per minute.

My question is, are there any limitation in J2SE that I should be aware of? For example http request pooling is poor, and I should use a 3rd pary app for that, or there is some kind of buffer, which might slow things down, etc.

Thanks,
krisy

Answer (score 0):

You should find an http client library spesifically done for that kind of traffic.I dont think the built-ins are suitable for such a high amount of requests. Apache httpClient might be a candidate.

Comment: Do you have anything to back up these feelings? Why wouldn't HttpURLConnection be suitable, but Apache HttpClient be?

Comment: HttpClient is made to be customized and it is generally a more complete solution while httpurlconnection and urlconnections are just a nice transparent way of accessing resources.

Comment: Yes, so what? Being more complete and customizable doesn't make it faster and more scalable magically.

Comment: There are a lot of addition features (cookie-handling, redirect handling, etc.), and my first idea is Apache HttpClient, yes :-)

Comment: once you have a good thread pool and a good (http) connection pool you can do pretty much everything without resorting to thirdy parts complex libs. Regarding HttpClient, sure is sugar, but has also some nasty limitations (specifically connection pooling needs quite a bit of attention)

Comment: By connection pooling, what do you mean? Like creating for example 50 HttpRequest objects, and reusing them?

Comment: the problem with connection pooling is that it works only if you are constantly connecting to the same servers. httpurlconnection is inflexible in my opinion. It is great if you need to constantly connect to the same server and do simple things. Try to do more complex stuff and it starts getting difficult.

Comment: and since you say "visit hundreds of websites" I assume you are doing something very http-specific on many sites, so you would benefit from the httpclient features, whereas httpurlconnection is mostly just a bit-pipe capable of accessing http urls.

Comment: @MarkusMikkolainen before deciding the best way I guess we need to know what's the meaning of visit (a fully featured web crawler ? - pooling is a good aid - simply a thousands post to various endpoints ? - pool can be useless). What he needs to do with output of the Http requests ? If performance "is" important, we cannot even exclude a native solution (good old C).

Comment: performance difference between java and c is currently in the worst case around 2x , so it shouldnt be an issue. I guess the biggest problem is how much you have to work with http, if you need to do a lot of http specific custom stuff, then httpclient is good, if you just need to fetch a lot of files from public web then httpurlconnection will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

The limitations that I am aware of in regard to the java.net http client are around authentication (it can be difficult to extend and does not really work all that well in a server environment where potentially different credentials need to be used to call the same URL), handling cookies, and constructing multi-part posts.

If these limitations either do not affect you or you find them easy to work around, I have found that the java.net client performs very well. I have also found it easier to work with when trying to utilize connection pooling for the purpose of taking advantage of http keep alive in a multi-threaded environment. As another person mentioned, this specifically is a difficult area with the Apache http client.